# Return a string of country codes from an argument that is a string of prices

Tags: python, string

So here's the question:

Write a function that will return a string of country codes from an argument that is a string of prices (containing dollar amounts following the country codes). Your function will take as an argument a string of prices like the following: `"US$40, AU$89, JP$200"`. In this example, the function would return the string `"US, AU, JP"`.

Hint: You may want to break the original string into a list, manipulate the individual elements, then make it into a string again.

Example:

```
> testEqual(get_country_codes("NZ$300, KR$1200, DK$5")
> "NZ, KR, DK"
```

As of now, I'm clueless as to how to separate the `$` and the numbers. I'm very lost.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Rather than simply asking for someone to write the code for you, please make an attempt to answer the question yourself, and then post a specific question seeking advice if you run into an issue you can't figure out, or if your code isn't working as expected. The [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) is a good starting point. Good luck!

Comment: `return ', '.join(i[:2] for i in input_list.split(','))`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid that code does not produce the output desired by the user though. you should do `input_list.split(', ')` the extra space is actually important ;)

Comment: @nbrooks Originally attacking the problem , I was able to split the string into a list with .split(). I split the list up with a for statement and I tried to get rid of "$300," with indices but I realized I needed the commas at the end so a [:2] wouldn't work. Also, I wasn't too sure how to bring those back into a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def test(string):
    return ", ".join([item.split("$")[0] for item in string.split(", ")])

string = "NZ$300, KR$1200, DK$5"
print test(string)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would advice using and looking up regex expressions 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

If you use re.findall it will return you a list of all matching strings, and you can use a regex expression like /[A-Z]{2}$ to find all the two letter capital words in the list.

After that you can just create a string from the resulting list.
Let me know if that is not clear

Answer (score -1):

Use a regular expression pattern and append the matches to a string. `(\w{2})\$` matches exactly 2 word characters followed by by a $.

```
def get_country_codes(string):
    matches = re.findall(r"(\w{2})\$", string)
    return ", ".join(match for match in matches)
```

Comment: You don't need a regular expression here, you can just pick the first two characters of each comma separated token.